# .htaccess: add www AND direct to a subfolder

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write an htaccess script that both automatically adds the www and pulls the contents from a subfolder.

Here's the script I'm using to pull from a subdirectory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# pointing for the domain abc.com to folder abc
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} abc.com
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !abc/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ abc/$1 [L]
```

Whenever I try to incorporate some code to automatically add www though it screws up in one way or another.

Comment: I suppose you do not have access to httpd.conf which can solve the problem within seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#Turn on rewriting
RewriteEngine on
# Rewrite the non www. version
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.abc.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abc.com/abc [L]
# Rewrite the www. version
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abc.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abc.com/abc [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I don't want the folder to be visible though. It's for hosting multiple sites.

Comment: Here's a fixed version that hides the sub folder.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Rewrite to include www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abc.com/ [L,R=301]

# Rewrite for the domain abc.com to folder abc
ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.abc\.com [NC]
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !abc/ [NC]
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ abc/$1 [L]
```

I like to escape any instance of . in a URL because in a regex a dot will match anything and generally I add the no case [NC] flag liberally. The first rule should redirect to include the www and the second rule should direct all other paths to the abc path.